# Perform step-by-step integral

Tags: matlab, loops, integral

I have this piece of code:

```
time = 614.4;
Uhub = 11;
HubHt = 90;
TI = 'A';
N1 = 4096;
N2 = 32;
N3 = 32;

L1 = Uhub*time;
L2 = 150;
L3 = 220;

V = L1*L2*L3;

gamma = 3.9;
c = 1.476;
b = 5.6;

if HubHt < 60
    lambda1 = 0.7*HubHt;
else
    lambda1 = 42;
end
L = 0.8*lambda1;

if isequal(TI,'A')
    Iref = 0.16;
    sigma1 = Iref*(0.75*Uhub + b);
elseif isequal(TI,'B')
    Iref = 0.14;
    sigma1 = Iref*(0.75*Uhub + b);
elseif isequal(TI,'C')
    Iref = 0.12;
    sigma1 = Iref*(0.75*Uhub + b);
else
    sigma1 = str2num(TI)*Uhub/100;
end

sigma_iso = 0.55*sigma1;


%% Wave number vectors
ik1 = cat(2,(-N1/2:-1/2),(1/2:N1/2));
ik2 = -N2/2:N2/2-1;
ik3 = -N3/2:N3/2-1;

[x y z] = ndgrid(ik1,ik2,ik3);

k1 = reshape((2*pi*L/L1)*x,N1*N2*N3,1);
k2 = reshape((2*pi*L/L2)*y,N1*N2*N3,1);
k3 = reshape((2*pi*L/L3)*z,N1*N2*N3,1);

k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
```

Now I should calculate

[image]

where

[image]

The procedure to calculate the integral is

[image]

At the moment I'm using this loop

```
E = @(k) (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));

E_int = zeros(1,N1*N2*N3);
E_int(1) = 1.5;
for i = 2:(N1*N2*N3) 
    E_int(i) = E_int(i) + quad(E,i-1,i);
end
```

neglecting for the k>400 approximation. I believe that my loop is not right.

How would you suggest to calculate the integral?

I thank you in advance.

WKR,
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of correction from the more obvious to the possibly more subtle. (Indeed I start from what you wrote in the final part going upwards).

From what you write:

```
 E = @(k) (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));

 E_int = zeros(1,N1*N2*N3);
 E_int(1) = 1.5;
 for i = 2:(N1*N2*N3) 
    %//No point in doing this:
    %//E_int(i) = E_int(i) + quad(E,i-1,i); 
    %//According to what you write, it should be:
    E_int(i) = E_int(i-1) + quad(E,i-1,i);     
 end
```

You could speed the whole thing up by doing

```
%//Independent integration on segments 
Local_int = arrayfun(@(i)quad(E,i-1,i), 2:(N1*N2*N3)); 
Local_int = [1.5  Local_int];
%//integral additivity
E_int = cumsum(Local_int);
```

---

**Moreover**, if the known condition (*point 2.*) really is "`... ( = 1.5 if k' = 0)`", **then the whole implementation should really be more like**

```
%//Independent integration on segments 
Local_int = arrayfun(@(i)quad(E,i-1,i), 2:(N1*N2*N3));      
%//integral additivity + cumulative removal of queues
E_int = 1.5 - [0 fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(Local_int)))]; %//To remove queues
```

Comment: but with this approach you, in the end, loose one point in E_int. In the case of N1*N2*N3 = 4096*17*17 E_int contanins 591871 elements instead of 591872, as supposed to be.

Comment: @FrancescoPerrone, right, there one more gui needed, which is exactly 1.5.

Comment: now E_int is N1*N2*N3 + 1 sized. I was more thinking to index i = 2:(N1*N2*N3)+1, like that E_int would match the N1*N2*N3 size.

Comment: Well, to me is correctly sized: 2:(N1*N2*N3) means N1*N2*N3-1 elements, E_int = 1.5 - [0 v...] is again N1*N2*N3, isn't it? fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(Local_int))) has N-1 elem, and [0 fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(Local_int)))] has N elem, infact. The difference 1.5- [0 fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(Local_int)))] doesn't change the total amount.

Comment: yep you're definitively right, I cheked it again and there was a mistake in one line of my code.